# How do I check the value of an enum in C?

Tags: c, enums

I'm reading through a library and found an enumeration that looks like this:

```
typedef enum
{
  IS_SYNCED    = 0;  //Determines if device is in/out of sync
  IS_VALID_REF = 1;  //Determines if device reference is valid
} EVENT;
```

I'm wondering how the to check what the value of `IS_SYNCED` would be?

Comment: The question is unclear as written. There is no relevance of `NULL`. Each enumerator has a value, and this author chose to give them explicit values, instead of using the default that we start at 0 and add one for each. Each instance of `EVENT` can have one value at a time. You would check for a given enumerator by comparing the instance of `EVENT` to that enumerator's value. What **is** not clear is whether a device can have a valid reference and be in sync, which you would expect... but that's a question for the author of the library, not SO: why they are declared as being mutually exclusive

Comment: `IS_SYNCED` *is* `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare enum values with `==`.

```
EVENT e = IS_SYNCED;

if(e == IS_SYNCED)
    printf("Is synced event\n");
else if(e == IS_VALID_REF)
    printf("Is valid ref event\n");
else
    printf("Unknown event\n");
```

prints:

```
Is synced event
```

You can also use `switch`:

```
EVENT e = IS_SYNCED;

switch(e) {
case IS_SYNCED:
    printf("Is synced event\n");
    break;
case IS_VALID_REF:
    printf("Is valid ref event\n");
    break;
default:
    printf("Unknown event\n");
    break;
}
```